# Getting errors installing the v7 support library so I can use the Toolbar class

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar

Today I installed rev 23.0.1 of the v7 support library to my project by adding the following line to the dependencies section of my build.gradle:

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
```

But now I get a ton of errors that look like this:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"ERROR","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material\u0027.","sourcePath":"/myproject/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1},"original":""}
```

...and ending with:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':MyApp:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/fruitman/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/build-tools-19.1.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

So I tried copy/pasting the exact line directly from the [setup instructions](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html):

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"
```

And now the gradle sync works but `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` is unresolved, which just happens to be the class I need. :(

Does anybody know how to install the right version of the support library so I can use the support Toolbar?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

After putting `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"` in your gradle file you also need to update the followings -

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
}
```

What might be happening here, AppCompat V7 trying to access things that exist in SDK version 23 and it not able to find them as your compileSdkVersion might be lower than 23.